# This is the stone where I carved my name=This is the stone into which I carved my name

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if the two sentences in the title mean the same thing.

This is the stone where I carved my name=This is the stone into which I carved my name.

Comment: Yes, in this context, they would mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes, and either could refer to a boulder in a field or a small stone in your pocket.

Comment: The second sounds more formal.